# How to use ajaxSend in select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

How can i use `.ajaxSend` within `select2` so that the event is triggered every time ajax call is made?

I tried something like:

```
$('a').select2({
  ajax: { send //code }
});
```

is there any better way to do it.

Comment: `$.ajaxSend` is a global event, and it's attached to the document, as in `$(document ).ajaxSend(...)` and will fire whenever an ajax request ***that uses jQuery's $.ajax*** is made.

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33949508/prevent-reload-of-data-with-select2-plugin-v4/34079165#34079165